# Webview not occupying entire layout in part of my screen

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using Absolute layout at some part of my screen and setting webview to absolute layout where it already has pinchzoom implemented seperatly.

I can able display webview using.

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams( );
content.addView(webView, lp);
```

But my layout not showing complete webview when zoom out but content like hyperlinks are occupying layout that i can observe when click on hyper link but it is not visible and showing blank with scrollbars at right and bottom.

How can i make webview to occupy the entire layout.
Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post your layout XML.

Comment: I am not doing through XML . I am doing dynamically with Absolute layout as I have mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do it programmatically, do something like this:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0);
content.addView(webView, lp);
```

Comment: sorry did not worked. the problem showing when i zoom out the screen. the absolute layout webview is not occupying the complete layout.